# C# parent child static variable access

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a few classes something like this:

```
public class Weapon
{
    public static int clip;
}

public class Uzi : Weapon{}
public class Ak47 : Weapon{}
```

Somewhere else in main code I have:

```
Uzi.clip = 5;
Ak47.clip = 1;
```

Will this work, will UZI have its own unique clip or same as AK47? If not how to achieve this?

This is simplified version above, what I have behind is much more complex but I just need an Idea how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: why even use static in this case?

Comment: Note that you haven't really indicated in the code that `Uzi` and `Ak47` inherit from Weapon.

Comment: Trying it would be faster, then writing this question.

Comment: @DStanley No I haven't it would take too much rewriting

Comment: Trying the simplified version here though would take just as long as asking. Even faster if you use LINQPad (works for non-Linq bits of C# too).

Comment: @user1188570 You could test it in 20 lines on code in a console app or LinqPad.  I know, I've seen me do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try it?

It does not work, as both referring to the same `clip`. (No difference here, but if it was a string you could test and prove they were the same object).

The best you can do is:

```
public abstract class Weapon
{
  public abstract int Clip{get;}//though my bow and sword are both weapons and neither has a clip...
}

public class Uzi : Weapon
{
  public override int Clip
  {
    get { return 5; }
  }
}
public class Ak47 : Weapon
{
  public override int Clip
  {
    get { return 1; }
  }
}
```

If you want individual weapons to have a `Clip` that differs then you want different code again.

Answer (score 4):

No.

`static` fields are not duplicated in derived classes.
`BaseClass.Field` and `DerivedClass.Field` compile to the same IL.

Comment: Thanks, btw where did you pick that from?

Comment: The easiest answer is that you pick it up by trying it out. It's suggested from a few other articles, for example in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3 under Static Members, where it talks about the fact that static methods cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

First, **inheritance**.

In order to `Uzi` be a `Weapon`, it must *inherit* from its base class. That is, `Uzi : Weapon`, and so for Ak47.

And then, **class x instance** variables.

When you declare a property as `static`, it's a *class* variable. That is, it does not belong to an *instance* (object) of that class, but to the class itself. So, if you have one `Uzi` and one `Ak47`, and you say that `MyUzi.clip = 20;`, `MyAk47` will have the same value.

So, in order to achieve what you're looking for, remove the `static` modifier.